# Gravitational and gauge-gravitational anomalies in ${\cal N}=1$ $D=4$ supergravity coupled to a SUSY gauge theory with chiral matter

Tags: string-theory, quantum-gravity, quantum-anomalies, supergravity

When people talk about the first superstring revolution they often mention the miraculous cancellation of anomalies via the Green-Schwarz mechanism. My question is whether such a string-theoretic mechanism is also at work when the 4D gravitational and gauge-gravitational anomalies are tackled? In this context, would it be fair to say that a possible discovery of superpartners at the LHC, which automatically implies some version of ${\cal N}=1$ $D=4$  supergravity, imply that stringy couplings (higher order in $\alpha'$) must be present in the corresponding Lagrangian to cancel the anomalies? What type of coupling are those?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are no purely gravitational anomalies in $D=4$. The one source of gauge-gravitational anomalies is a triangle diagram with one gauge vertex and two graviton vertices. This vanishes provided that ${\rm Tr}_L Q=0$ where the trace runs over all left-handed fermions and $Q$ is the gauge generator with the potential anomaly. In the SM the only potential nonzero contribution arises from taking $Q=Y$, where $Y$ is the generator of the
$U(1)$ part of $SU(3) \times SU(2) \times U(1)$. In the SM with standard fermion assignments this trace vanishes. In string compactifications one often gets additional $U(1)$ symmetries, and sometimes one finds these are anomalous by the above criterion. In such situations one finds a version of the Green-Schwarz mechanism involving a coupling of an axion-like mode
to the gauge field which ends up giving a mass to the $U(1)$ gauge field. The axion-like field arises in string theory as a two-form field $B$, but in $D=4$ one can dualize to a scalar via $H=dB=*da$.

Comment: Thank you @Jeff Harvey! Are there anomalies when one couples the MSSM with the global (spontaneously broken) $U(1)$ Peccei-Quinn symmetry of the axion to supergravity? Is this one of the possible additional $U(1)$s you mentioned above?

Comment: @ Jeff Harvey. I agree that it's not straightforward but it's quite possible. Vacua with potentially many ultra-light string axions where all the geometric moduli are very heavy have been constructed here: http://www.springerlink.com/content/2845m53jmpw5754h/

Comment: Dear @stringpheno, some of the 10D Green-Schwarz anomaly cancellation mechanisms are almost directly inherited in $d=4$ and are important, see e.g. http://www.sciencedirect.com/science?_ob=ArticleURL&_udi=B6TVN-46YD43B-10D&_user=10&_coverDate=11/21/1991&_rdoc=1&_fmt=high&_orig=search&_origin=search&_sort=d&_docanchor=&view=c&_rerunOrigin=scholar.google&_acct=C000050221&_version=1&_urlVersion=0&_userid=10&md5=bc4ecc19b2bf8dd3a9fd44c8ed8e2ac2&searchtype=a - and many other papers by Ferrara (et al.) from the 1980s and early 1990s.

Comment: Two more papers that allow you to believe that the discovery of SUSY, in a world with gravity, would pretty much imply that a string-like Green-Schwarz mechanism is necessary, and in this sense, a discovery of SUSY could also be a proof of string theory: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science?_ob=ArticleURL&_udi=B6TVN-486T3SS-CG&_user=10&_coverDate=02/26/1987&_rdoc=1&_fmt=high&_orig=search&_origin=search&_sort=d&_docanchor=&view=c&_searchStrId=1640075252&_rerunOrigin=scholar.google&_acct=C000050221&_version=1&_urlVersion=0&_userid=10&md5=f4a01cdd648e279b4196357a6cd59361&searchtype=a

Comment: The second paper: http://cdsweb.cern.ch/record/180015/files/CM-P00062405.pdf?version=1 - as discussed above, you need the "linear multiplets" which remember the $B$ field from 10 dimensions and the axion that it produces in $d=4$. You will find an equivalent condition if you restrict yourself to "conformal supergravities", too. The argument is not quite waterproof but it's very likely to hold.

Comment: Thank you very much @Luboš Motl ! Would you please sum up your comments and post them as an answer?

Comment: Dear @stringpheno, I actually want to sort exactly this question more properly in my head, to see whether it will deserve a post on my blog that would be called "Discovery of SUSY by the LHC de facto proves string theory." :-) I can't claim it now (when even SUSY hasn't been seen, and ATLAS just published their 35/pb new bounds for SUSY), at the level I usually require for similar big statements, so at this moment, I would view my comment just as a view on (mostly) Jeff Harvey's official answer from a slightly different angle. Now I don't really have much more to say than what is above.

Comment: On the topic of string axions (maybe too tangential to the original topic): getting the imaginary part of a modulus to be stabilized at a much lower mass than the real part is only the first step in having a phenomenologically viable QCD axion. One also has to check that any other instantons induce a *much* smaller mass than QCD does (high axion "quality"). Then there is the problem that in a conventional axion cosmology, string-scale decay constants overclose the universe. There seems to be a widespread ossified conventional wisdom that this is the "anthropic axion window." (continued...)

Comment: That is, anthropically you can select a small initial angle. This tends to be the only possibility people mention, but there's a  much more palatable answer (from my point of view). Namely, these scenarios almost always involve relatively light moduli that dominate the energy density at some point, so the axion can begin oscillating during a matter-dominated phase (from coherent oscillations of the moduli) rather than the usual radiation-dominated phase. This can lead to weaker bounds, although one still has to be careful and solve the moduli problems as well as the axion abundance problem.

Comment: (One reference, out of many, is http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0210256)

Comment: Thanks @Matt Reece ! I absolutely agree with you that the late-time moduli-domination scenario is much more elegant than the anthropic BS and, in fact, this is the more typical situation in string compactifications with stabilized moduli. The paper I referred to in my comment to Jeff Harvey has precisely this property, i.e. multiple light moduli with masses $O(m_{3/2})$ but less than $2\times m_{3/2}$ that may dominate the energy density at late times but decay before BBN.

Comment: The high quality of the axions can be easily achieved with the E3 instanton 4-cycle volumes of order $\alpha_{GUT}^{-1}\sim 25$ - a very natural value (the extra factor of $2\pi$ in the exponential helps a lot here :) ).

Comment: See eq. (5.2) in that reference.

Comment: Great, @Matt Reece. Would you agree then that if we had experimental evidence of SUSY and axions that solve the strong CP-problem, that would also imply that there has to be a stringy-like Green-Schwarz mechanism (mixing loops with tree diagrams)?

Comment: @Luboš Motl, you'll have to fill in more of the argument for me to understand where you're going with this, I think. Certainly an axion that solves strong CP can't be eaten to become the longitudinal mode of a heavy gauge boson.

Answer (score 0):

In 4D, we can have an axion mechanism. We have the axion-gauge coupling $\int d^4x\, d^2\theta \, \Phi W^\alpha W_\alpha$. But there are no gauge or gravitational anomalies in MSSM!

Comment: I was not talking about the global SUSY limit, please read my question carefully! The MSSM in the rigid limit has no gauge anomalies but when embedded into N=1 D=4 supergravity, which is automatic since the super-Poincare symmetry must also be local, one generates the anomalies I was asking about.